# The MSE after each synchronization block doesn't go consistently down at the output of each block

Tags: digital-communications, synchronization

I have a synchronization chain that consists of

1. Coarse frequency synchronization block
2. Frame synchronization block
3. Symbol time synchronization block
4. Fine frequency synchronization block
5. PLL phase synchronization block

I would like to study the MSE after each synchronization block between the channel input and the output of that block. To do this I introduced a frequency offset, a phase noise, and a time offset to the channel input signal.

By doing so, I noticed something unexpected: when the whole synchronization block is not active, I get an MSE value of let's say $x$, but when I turn the coarse frequency synchronization block (while the other synchronization blocks are off), I get an MSE of $y > x$. I was expecting the MSE to consistently go down after each block. Am I wrong in assuming that?

Comment: Have you verified each block on its own? For example, does your coarse frequency sync give the answer that you expect (as well as the other blocks)?

Comment: How does one determine MSE meaningfully without all – Frequency, time and phase synchronization?

Comment: @Engineer When I introduce frequency offset only to the signal and then turn on the coarse frequency synchronization block, then yes, it does.

Comment: @MarcusMüller But even after the signal goes through all the synchronization blocks, i.e., all blocks are turned on, the mse is still higher than without a synchronization block. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure, any step in a chain of steps can have bugs, for example

Comment: @MarcusMüller Are you implying the synchronization block might not be correctly implemented, or that might be possible even if everything is correctly implemented?

Comment: both, I just don't know! Every correction is an estimator, estimators have variance, hence make mistakes. Furthermore, they are typically control systems, and as such have dynamic behavior like overshoot. And, they are often designed by humans for imperfect systems, and thus have implementation and platform bugs.